# Check internet connection via DNS

Tags: java, sockets, dns, connection

I'm writing a Java program and I often face the problem that antivirus software block internet connection when users download my application.

So, I found an interesting way how to check internet access if it's blocked by antivirus: I use sockets and try to connect to Google DNS via 53 port.
E.g. avast don't block this connection and I can understand - does user has a real internet connection or not.

```
public static boolean checkRealInternetConnection() {
    return checkInternet("8.8.8.8", 53);
}

private static boolean checkInternet(String host, int port) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 5000);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, my question: is this good solution?

P.S. If user has a real internet connection and doesn't have connection to my website via port 80 - I show a message that antivirus software can block connection.

Comment: If antivirus software is blocking port 80 to your website then it presumably blocks port 80 to every web-site; I doubt such an antivirus product would be very successful in the market. Why do you believe antivirus software is blocking your application?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, a lot of my users write complaints that my app can't connect to the internet and to solve this problem they should turn off antivirus. By the way my app doesn't have a digital signature and antiviruses think that it dangerous.

Comment: It might be better to include that warning on application start-up then. You might also consider adding a digital signature, because disabling anti-virus to use an application is something that I would not (personally) do.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, digital signature costs more than $100. I can't afford this now. I will do this later.